# C# unable to display RAW16 grayscale image with correct color mapping

Tags: c#, .net, image, picturebox

Modifying the code provided in this link:

[Original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290631/how-to-display-raw-data-as-an-image-visual-studio-c)

I wrote this:

```cs
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(txtPicture.Text))
        {
            byte[] _data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(txtPicture.Text);

            var _rgbData = Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb16(_data, 160, 120);
            var _bmp = CreateBitmapFromBytes(_rgbData, 160, 120);

            pbFrame.Image = _bmp;
        }
    }

    private static void Convert16bitGSToRGB(UInt16 color, out byte red, out byte green, out byte blue)
    {
        red = (byte)(color & 0x31);
        green = (byte)((color & 0x7E0) >> 5);
        blue = (byte)((color & 0xF800) >> 11);
    }

    private static byte[] Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb48(byte[] inBuffer, int width, int height)
    {
        int inBytesPerPixel = 2;
        int outBytesPerPixel = 6;

        byte[] outBuffer = new byte[width * height * outBytesPerPixel];
        int inStride = width * inBytesPerPixel;
        int outStride = width * outBytesPerPixel;

        // Step through the image by row
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // Step through the image by column
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                // Get inbuffer index and outbuffer index
                int inIndex = (y * inStride) + (x * inBytesPerPixel);
                int outIndex = (y * outStride) + (x * outBytesPerPixel);

                byte hibyte = inBuffer[inIndex + 1];
                byte lobyte = inBuffer[inIndex];

                //R
                outBuffer[outIndex] = lobyte;
                outBuffer[outIndex + 1] = hibyte;

                //G
                outBuffer[outIndex + 2] = lobyte;
                outBuffer[outIndex + 3] = hibyte;

                //B
                outBuffer[outIndex + 4] = lobyte;
                outBuffer[outIndex + 5] = hibyte;
            }
        }
        return outBuffer;
    }

    private static byte[] Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb16(byte[] inBuffer, int width, int height)
    {
        int inBytesPerPixel = 2;
        int outBytesPerPixel = 2;

        byte[] outBuffer = new byte[width * height * outBytesPerPixel];
        int inStride = width * inBytesPerPixel;
        int outStride = width * outBytesPerPixel;

        // Step through the image by row
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // Step through the image by column
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                // Get inbuffer index and outbuffer index
                int inIndex = (y * inStride) + (x * inBytesPerPixel);
                int outIndex = (y * outStride) + (x * outBytesPerPixel);

                byte hibyte = inBuffer[inIndex];
                byte lobyte = inBuffer[inIndex+1];

                outBuffer[outIndex] = lobyte;
                outBuffer[outIndex+1] = hibyte;
            }
        }

        return outBuffer;
    }

    private static byte[] Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb24(byte[] inBuffer, int width, int height)
    {
        int inBytesPerPixel = 2;
        int outBytesPerPixel = 3;

        byte[] outBuffer = new byte[width * height * outBytesPerPixel];
        int inStride = width * inBytesPerPixel;
        int outStride = width * outBytesPerPixel;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int inIndex = (y * inStride) + (x * inBytesPerPixel);
                int outIndex = (y * outStride) + (x * outBytesPerPixel);

                byte hibyte = inBuffer[inIndex];
                byte lobyte = inBuffer[inIndex + 1];

                byte r, g, b;

                UInt16 color = (UInt16)(hibyte << 8 | lobyte);

                Convert16bitGSToRGB(color, out r, out g, out b);

                outBuffer[outIndex] = r;
                outBuffer[outIndex + 1] = g;
                outBuffer[outIndex + 2] = b;
            }
        }

        return outBuffer;
    }

    private static Bitmap CreateBitmapFromBytes(byte[] pixelValues, int width, int height)
    {
        //Create an image that will hold the image data

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);

        //Get a reference to the images pixel data
        Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData picData = bmp.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

        //Copy the pixel data into the bitmap structure
        Marshal.Copy(pixelValues, 0, pixelStartAddress, pixelValues.Length);

        bmp.UnlockBits(picData);
        return bmp;
    }
```

But still the result of the conversion is not satisfying/correct. This's the picture I should get:

[image: Original picture]

Converting the file linked here:

[Example RAW16 picture file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yznl6c3aQDHLcJsY_xT61WUJKn0gkWpd)

This's the result using `Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb48`:

[image]

This's the result using `Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb16`:

[image: GrayScaleToRgb16]

This's the result using `Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb24`:

[image: GrayScaleToRgb24]

It's quite clear that the color remapping is wrong but I cant understand where the problem is.

Additionally I also found that picturebox didn't show exactly what it stores. The second image from the top (`Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb48` result) is what the picturebox shows while the following picture is what I obtain if I save the image shown in PNG format:

[image: Image saved]

I tought RAW16 grayscale should mean 2 bytes containing either a 16 bit gray value or an RGB gray value encoded on a 565 or 555 map. But none of those hypotesis seems to match the real thing.

Someone has an hint on how to convert the value provided in the source file to obtain a picture like the first one (obtained from the same source using ImageJ)?

Comment: If you save the Image built with `PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb` to a PNG file, you probably have something near the result you're expecting.

Comment: @Jimi not. Uhm... not really. The picture saved is something different from what the picturebox depicts but it's not correct anyway: [48bpp image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HN68KHwGR-nhWvxpYxzDBQn7fbD13Qpc)

Comment: Yes, well, raw 16Bit Grayscale images are not exactly supported. That's what the encoder can do, transcoding to 8 bits per channel. The color space won't be correctly adjusted. You'll have to perform the normalization yourself. Btw, the raw image you posted, opened with PhotoShop, gives the same exact result (similar to over-exposure: localized loss of resolution). It might be targeting some specific decoder, similar to DICOM image format (for microscope or x-ray).

Comment: @Jimi nope! Problems were 1) endianism 2) luminance range 3) picturebox. The last one in particular (maybe depending on the graphic card) seems to be responsible of a failure in rendering of 48bpp frames.

Comment: :) That's why I suggested to use the PNG encoder to perform the conversion. And to normalize the color space. Since nobody knows anything about this image, what produced it and with what parameters - also considering that PhotoShop produces the same results as the PNG encoder - there isn't much more that one can say.

Comment: @Jimi as I stated saving to PNG certified the problem in picturebox rendering. The other issues where mainly due to incorrect handling of the format. Prior start I have taken into account a probabile problem in endianism but I've been fooled by the overlapping issue on the dynamic range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possibile hint using **GIMP**. If I load the original file trough this app (changing extension in `.data` and/or forcing to load it as RAW) and setting it as a `160x120 16bpp BigEndian` I got a nearly black frame (!), but if I change levels compressing the range around the only small peak present (around 12,0 black - 13,0 white) the image result correct. Changing endianism is pretty straightforward compressing the dynamic range a little less but I'm working on it.

The first lesson learned in this experience is "*Don't trust your eyes*" :-).

The final result of my efforts are these three methods:

```
public static void GetMinMax(byte[] data, out UInt16 min, out UInt16 max, bool big_endian = true)
{
    if (big_endian)
        min = max = (UInt16)((data[0] << 8) | data[1]);
    else
        min = max = (UInt16)((data[1] << 8) | data[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < (data.Length - 1); i += 2)
    {
        UInt16 _value;

        if (big_endian)
            _value = (UInt16)((data[i] << 8) | data[i + 1]);
        else
            _value = (UInt16)((data[i + 1] << 8) | data[i]);

        if (_value < min)
            min = _value;

        if (_value > max)
            max = _value;
    }
}

public static void CompressRange(byte MSB, byte LSB, UInt16 min, UInt16 max, out byte color, Polarity polarity)
{
    UInt16 _value = (UInt16)((MSB << 8) | LSB);

    _value -= min;

    switch (polarity)
    {
        case Polarity.BlackHot:
            _value = (UInt16)((_value * 255) / (max - min));
            _value = (UInt16)(255 - _value);
            break;

        default:
        case Polarity.WhiteHot:
            _value = (UInt16)((_value * 255) / (max - min));
            break;
    }

    color = (byte)(_value & 0xff);
}

public static byte[] Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb24(byte[] inBuffer, int width, int height, UInt16 min, UInt16 max, bool big_endian = true, Polarity polarity = Polarity.WhiteHot)
{
    int inBytesPerPixel = 2;
    int outBytesPerPixel = 3;

    byte[] outBuffer = new byte[width * height * outBytesPerPixel];
    int inStride = width * inBytesPerPixel;
    int outStride = width * outBytesPerPixel;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int inIndex = (y * inStride) + (x * inBytesPerPixel);
            int outIndex = (y * outStride) + (x * outBytesPerPixel);

            byte hibyte;
            byte lobyte;

            if (big_endian)
            {
                hibyte = inBuffer[inIndex];
                lobyte = inBuffer[inIndex + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                hibyte = inBuffer[inIndex + 1];
                lobyte = inBuffer[inIndex];
            }

            byte gray;

            CompressRange(hibyte, lobyte, min, max, out gray, polarity);

            outBuffer[outIndex] = gray;
            outBuffer[outIndex + 1] = gray;
            outBuffer[outIndex + 2] = gray;
        }
    }

    return outBuffer;
}
```

These allows to load the file attached to the original question and display it on a standard `WindowsForm PictureBox`. Using 48bpp format will result in a degraded image on some graphic cards (at least on mine).
BTW `GetMinMax` calculate min max value on the current frame regardless of the history of the environment. This means that if you are going to use this functions to display a picture sequence (as I am) a strong variation of average temperature in the FOV will drive the overall image to a different *exposure* resulting in loosing some details of the picture. In such cases I suggest to calculate min-max over the current frame but NON to use it in `Convert16BitGrayScaleToRgb24` using instead a *moving average* for both values.